# Unable to scrape similar links from different depth out of a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've created a script in python to parse different links from a webpage. There are two section in the landing page. One is `Top Experiences` and the other is `More Experiences`. My current attempt can fetch the links from both the categories.

The type of links I wanna collect are (few of them) under the `Top Experiences` section at this moment. However, when I traverse the links under `More Experiences` section, I can see that they all lead to the page in which there is a section named `Experiences` under which there are links that are similar to the links under `Top Experiences` in the landing page. I wanna grab them all.

One such desirable link I'm after looks like: `https://www.airbnb.com/experiences/20712?source=seo`.

[website link](https://www.airbnb.com/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L0-0)

My current attempt fetches the links from both the categories:

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.airbnb.com/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L0-0"

def get_links(link):
    res = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    items = [urljoin(link,item.get("href")) for item in soup.select("div[style='margin-top:16px'] a._1f0v6pq")]
    return items

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for item in get_links(URL):
        print(item)
```

> How can I parse all the links under `Top Experiences` section along with the links under `Experiences` section that can be found upon traversing the links under `More Experiences`?

***Please [check out the image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/malepxpijbzhsbk/Untitled3.jpg?dl=0) if anything unclear. I used a pen available in paint so the writing may be a little hard to understand.***

Answer (score 1):

Process:

1. Get all `Top Experiences` links
2. Get all `More Experiences` links
3. Send a request to all `More Experiences` links one by one and get the links under `Experiences` in each page.

The `div` under which the links are present are same for all the pages have the same class `_12kw8n71`

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
from random import randint
URL = "https://www.airbnb.com/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L0-0"
res = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
top_experiences= [urljoin(URL,item.get("href")) for item in soup.find_all("div",class_="_12kw8n71")[0].find_all('a')]
more_experiences= [urljoin(URL,item.get("href")) for item in soup.find_all("div",class_="_12kw8n71")[1].find_all('a')]
generated_experiences=[]
#visit each link in more_experiences
for url in more_experiences:
    sleep(randint(1,10))#avoid blocking by putting some delay
    generated_experiences.extend([urljoin(URL,item.get("href")) for item in soup.find_all("div",class_="_12kw8n71")[0].find_all('a')])
```

Notes:

1. Your required links will be present in three lists `top_experiences` , `more_experiences` and `generated_experiences`
2. I have added random delay to avoid getting blocked.
3. Not printing the lists as it will be too long.

   `top_experiences` - 50 links

   `more_experiences` - 299 links

   `generated_experiences` -14950 links

Answer (score 1):

The solution is slightly tricky. It can be achieved in several ways. The one I find most useful is use the links under `More Experiences` within `get_links()` function recursively. All the links under `More Experiences` have a common keyword `_pdp-`.

So, when you define condional statement within the function to make the links sieve through the function `get_links()` recursively then the `else` block will produces the desired links. Most important thing to notice is that all the desired links are within the class `_1f0v6pq` So the logic of getting the links is fairly easy .

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.airbnb.com/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L0-0"

def get_links(link):
    res = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select("div[style='margin-top:16px'] a._1f0v6pq"):
        if "_pdp-" in item.get("href"):
            get_links(urljoin(URL,item.get("href")))
        else:
            print(urljoin(URL,item.get("href")))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_links(URL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seem like both the "Top Experience" and "More experiences" links share the same class so you can just use `.find_all` to obtain the links.

```py
import requests
#from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# URL to scrape
url = "https://www.airbnb.com/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L0-0"

# Make request and Initialize BS4 with request content
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "lxml")

# Tag that contains "Top Experiences" and "More Experiences"
soup.find_all(class_="_l8g1fr")

# Test Code
#Prints title of links and the href
links = soup.find_all(class_="_l8g1fr")
for link in links:
    print(link.find("a").get_text())
    print(link.find("a").get('href'))
```

Refactor code to meet your coding paradigm.

Comment: Perhaps, this is my limitation that I could not make you understand what I was trying to achieve @Erick Guerra. The same type of links are also available under `Experiences` section in concerning pages if you follow the links under `More Experiences`. I wanna grab them all. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can scrape from the `div`s with `class` `"_12kw8n71"`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
d = soup(requests.get('https://www.airbnb.com/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L0-0').text, 'html.parser')
a, b, *_ = d.find_all('div', {'class':'_12kw8n71'})
result = {'top_experiences':[[i.text, i['href']] for i in a.find_all('a')], 'more_experiences':[[i.text, i['href']] for i in b.find_all('a')]}
```

Output (Only top experiences and part of the links from more experiences, as the full output exceeds Stackoverflow's character limit):

```
{'top_experiences': [["#1 HOLLYWOOD SIGN TOUR - WORLD'S BEST", '/experiences/26790?source=seo'], ['**#1-COMEDY/INSTAGRAM HOLLYWOOD WALK**', '/experiences/94033?source=seo'], ["A Potter's Wheel in Brooklyn", '/experiences/139532?source=seo'], ['Absolute: Seoul Pub Crawl & Party', '/experiences/161886?source=seo'], ['Amsterdam Experience Cruise', '/experiences/145329?source=seo'], ['Argentine Tango classes in London', '/experiences/241771?source=seo'], ['Axe throwing Canadian Experience', '/experiences/372251?source=seo'], ['Be a chocolate maker for a day', '/experiences/161912?source=seo'], ['Chianti in a Glass', '/experiences/179469?source=seo'], ['Cooking class in the Chianti Hills', '/experiences/25122?source=seo'], ['Cycle and Snack through hidden Bangkok', '/experiences/315116?source=seo'], ['Discover Valpolicella', '/experiences/77468?source=seo'], ["Don't watch Soweto, be part of Soweto", '/experiences/243188?source=seo'], ['Explore Pompeii w/ an Archaeologist', '/experiences/176605?source=seo'], ['Explore backstreets with a historian', '/experiences/90528?source=seo'], ['Explore the hidden food gems of Athens', '/experiences/256850?source=seo'], ['Fall and Winter Forest Trail Rides', '/experiences/236040?source=seo'], ['Foodies of Palermo - street food tour', '/experiences/212673?source=seo'], ['Forge a silver ring with jewellers', '/experiences/209198?source=seo'], ['Handmade Family Pasta & Tiramisù', '/experiences/115906?source=seo'], ['Hidden Gems of Old Delhi', '/experiences/154177?source=seo'], ['Hike Runyon Canyon with a rescue dog', '/experiences/82265?source=seo'], ['Hike Table Mountain with a Guide!', '/experiences/137248?source=seo'], ['Kayak in La Jolla', '/experiences/132375?source=seo'], ['Lakehouse Jazz', '/experiences/53239?source=seo'], ["Lisbon's best flavors", '/experiences/64564?source=seo'], ["London's Top Sights Tour : Fun Guide!", '/experiences/203605?source=seo'], ['Make ramen noodles from scratch', '/experiences/61279?source=seo'], ['Mount Etna excursion and lava tubes', '/experiences/221142?source=seo'], ['Must Have L.A. Pictures!', '/experiences/59665?source=seo'], ['MySurf School Bali', '/experiences/153910?source=seo'], ['PASTAMANIA', '/experiences/103280?source=seo'], ['Paddle with the Penguins', '/experiences/112515?source=seo'], ['Paella Maestro', '/experiences/51311?source=seo'], ["Paris' Best Kept Secrets Tour", '/experiences/113388?source=seo'], ['Play, Walk & Feed  Anteaters +Kinkajou', '/experiences/270405?source=seo'], ['Red Dunes Safari & BBQ @The Real Camp', '/experiences/105242?source=seo'], ['San José Chocolate Tasting Tour', '/experiences/280822?source=seo'], ['Snorkel in Manly with a local expert', '/experiences/66873?source=seo'], ['Sunrise SUP into Caves & Grottos', '/experiences/242911?source=seo'], ['Sushi-making Experience', '/experiences/53271?source=seo'], ['Swim with sea lions in their natural habitat', '/experiences/327235?source=seo'], ['The Drinking & Prohibition walk', '/experiences/102778?source=seo'], ['The Ultimate Harry Potter Walking Tour', '/experiences/188432?source=seo'], ['Tsukiji (Old) vs Toyosu (New) S.S Tour', '/experiences/71924?source=seo'], ['Wolf Encounter', '/experiences/47240?source=seo'], ['XXL Wild&Organic Roman food: Eat&Learn', '/experiences/161461?source=seo'], ['Your First Chinese Seal-engraving Work', '/experiences/166172?source=seo'], ['Под руку с духами по старой Москве', '/experiences/94558?source=seo'], ["⭐BIKE to taste the world's BEST TACOS!", '/experiences/75047?source=seo']], 'more_experiences': [[" Flying Trapeze  - 'Ten Things I Hate About You' Tour", '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-0'], ["'The Devil in the White City' Tour - 23:59 in Paris", '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-1'], ["24h en Republica Dominicana - 80s  Cover Band's Secret Gig[FUKUOKA]", '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-2'], ['80s Nights - A Journey Through History', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-3'], ["A Journey for the Tastebuds, in Malaga - A Tea Sommelier's Zen Tea Party", '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-4'], ['A Time for Home - A music walk with a french composer', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-5'], ['A musical walk in Salzburg - ANALOG PHOTOGRAPHY in DC!  Shoot FILM!', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-6'], ['ANGEL, ENERGIA GASTRONOMICA ANCESTRAL! - Acuarela al aire libre en Poblenou', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-7'], ['Acupuncture in Historic Clinic - Afternoon tea at the Casavant Villa', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-8'], ["Afterwork dans un Atelier d'Artistes - Alpine Raft Expérience", '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-9'], ['Alpine Tour Skiing Uphill/Downhill - Amélie en live!', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-10'], ['An African Dance & Cultural Experience - Another BKK', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-11'], ['Another Etna: Trekking, Food and Wine - Aprende o perfecciona bailes caribeños', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-12'], ['Aprende una actividad unica de Oaxaca - Around historical area with lovely dog', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-13'], ['Around the Neva & its embankments - Art tour Soumaya & Jumex Museums visit', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-14'], ['Art tour at Bellas Artes - Ascent to the crater of the Puracé volcano', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-15'], ['Asciende a la cima del Batea Mahuida - Atlas Mountains Day Trip: imlil Valley', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-16'], ['Atlas Mountains Full day Cultural Trip - Authentic Tango Night', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-17'], ['Authentic Tango with Live Music - BIARRITZ WALKING HISTORICAL TOUR', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-18'], ['BIG SUP Fun - Paddle Sevilla! - Bake ‘Dorayaki’ Japanese pancake', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-19'], ['Bakery Hop with Perth Brunch Bloggers - Banyuatis-Munduk Amazing Bike Tour', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-20'], ["Baptism of Rome for First-Timers - Batik: What's That?", '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-21'], ['Batom vermelho - um estilo de vida - Beach Exercise Under The Sun', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-22'], ['Beach FlowJAM - Become Captain of the Day with Vicky', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-23'], ['Become Reiki 1 Certified in Hawaii! - Beginner Workshop', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-24'], ['Beginner and Kid Friendly Kayak Tour - Best Croissants + Coffee of Paris Walk', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-25'], ['Best Dirt Biking Experience in KL! - Big Easy Food Tours', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-26'], ['Big Fish In The Big Apple - Bike the Wineries', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-27'], ['Bike the local backroads - Birdwatching al Parco del Circeo', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-28'], ['Birdwatching and camping - Boat Trip at Arrabida with Lunch', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-29'], ['Boat Trip to historic Clonmacnoise - Boozin in Brooklyn: Spirits & Beer', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-30'], ["Boozy Icy Secrets - Breakfast Coffee Yoga @ Kellogg's Cafe", '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-31'], ['Breakfast With The (Chicago) Bear - Brugge voor jou.', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-32'], ['Brumby (wild) Horse Experience - Bushwalk with Bob', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-33'], ["Bushwalking; Airlie's best kept secret - Cabalgata, pasión por la aventura.", '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-34'], ['Cabalgatas "Buscando el sol de ayer" - Camina por el parque observando aves', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-35'], ['Camina por la Historia de  Jujuy - Canoeing with Champagne and Pastries', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-36'], ['Canoeing, Kayaking, Cycling in Catba - Capture your relationship in photos', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-37'], ['Capture your smile in beautiful hanbok - Catalonia Sailing Xperience', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-38'], ['Catalonia from Above - Cervantes Tapas Crawl Alcalá d Henares', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-39'], ['Cervezas artesanales de Querétaro - Cherry blossom viewing party in Ueno', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-40'], ['Cherry blossoms and your photo session - Chocolate tasting and tour', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-41'], ['Chocolate therapy - City Tour With Visit to Teatro Colon', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-42'], ['City Tour around Cali - Climb a sea cliff in El Empordà coast', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-43'], ['Climb an iconic hill with an instructor - Cocktails and Canapés', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-44'], ['Cocktails and Canvas - Columbia River King Salmon Fishing', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-45'], ['Columbus Cemetery. History and Art - Conhecendo o centro do recife', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-46'], ['Conhecendo o litoral e as belas praias - Cook  great traditional dish with Heba', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-47'], ['Cook  with Cristiana and Mamma Nora - Cook shelf mania.. authentic n savory', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-48'], ['Cook tapas at a secret private eatery - Cooking Spanish "tapas"', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-49'], ['Cooking Spanish classics with Soul! - Copenhagen Skyline Art Workshop', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-50'], ['Copenhagen Small Group Tour - Couture dans un atelier de Montmartre', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-51'], ["Covered Walkways Through a Writer’s Eyes - Crawlin' in the City - Bar Crawl", '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-52'], ["Crazy French Sauces - Create a Story in a Writer's Retreat", '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-53'], ['Create a Travel Journal - Create with a pro tie-dye artist', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-54'], ['Create wooden guitar picks and jewelry - Creative Raw Vegan Cooking Workshop', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-55'], ['Creative Rendezvous in Copenhagen - Créer ses cosmétiques naturels (DIY)', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-56'], ['Créer un Mandala Energétique - Cupcake Bake & Decorate - Spitalfields', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-57'], ['Cupcake Bouquet Class - Cycling in quiet NE. Connecticut.', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-58'], ['Cycling in the Don Valley - DJ WORKSHOP IN AACHEN GEBE DEN TAKT AN', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-59'], ['DJ Workshop and Indie Scene Night - Dark tour of Split', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-60'], ['Darkroom Photography in Kuala Lumpur - Decorative Wreath Workshop', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-61'], ['Decoupage for DIY memorabilia & gifts - Descubre México a través de la foto', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-62'], ['Descubre Playa Blanca, Saltos - Design a Garment in the World Market', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-63'], ['Design a game level in a game studio - Dinghy Sailing at El Portet', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-64'], ['Dingle Traditional Rowing - Discover CDMX from the best Rooftops', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-65'], ['Discover Caen "Art de vivre" - Discover Manzanita Scavenger Hunt', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-66'], ["Discover Marrakech Secrets by Bike - Discover Tarraco's living history", '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-67'], ['Discover Tarragona coast from the sea - Discover nd paint your Aztec protector', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-68'], ['Discover new flavors with an oenophile - Discover the cosmos', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-69'], ['Discover the emotion of Kitesurf - Discovering Montjuic Hill', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-70'], ['Discovering Old Medina of Casablanca - Diving, Dipping, Swiming in Varadero', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-71'], ['Dj Workshop - Downtown Toronto Photoshoot Experience', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-72'], ['Downtown Traditional Cantina Pub Crawl - Drinking&Eating with Tokyohandsomeboy', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-73'], ['Drinks and  a Show Walking Tour - Découverte des dauphins', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-74'], ['Découverte des spiritueux québécois - EL FASCINANTE MUNDO DEL MOSAICO', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-75'], ['ELDORADO: sus plantas y lugares. - Eat Like a Local - Dinner Experience', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-76'], ['Eat Like a Local at Butterworth - Eco Friendly Ranch & Petting Zoo', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-77'], ['Eco Hike in Pinar del Rio - Electric Skateboard down Paris', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-78'], ['Electric Skateboard the Highline Canal - Enigmatic / Sintra', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-79'], ['Enjoin Local Meal By Taking Vegetable - Enjoy local food experience in Tokyo!', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-80'], ['Enjoy local western part of Jeju ! - Escalada en Roca en Acantilados Valpo', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-81'], ['Escalada en Tarifa - Everyone Can Dance! Brussels', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-82'], ['Everyone can do Calligraphy - Experience Fabulous698B! Spring menu!', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-83'], ['Experience Falconry Firsthand - Experience a tasting menu in Saigon', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-84'], ['Experience a traditional Sunday lunch - Experiencia de golf en Buenos Aires', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-85'], ['Experiencia de un día en Salamanca - Explore Bowen Island Walking Adventure', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-86'], ['Explore Brazilian cuisine with a chef - Explore Korea broadcast Town & MBC', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-87'], ['Explore Korčula with Art historian - Explore Saratoga Passage by Kayak', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-88'], ['Explore Sceneries of Sokcho - Explore city nightlife with a musician', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-89'], ['Explore city nightlife with locals! - Explore the Old District Sham Shui Po', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-90'], ['Explore the Oslo Wilderness in Kayak - Exploring  Maspalomas by E-Scooter', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-91'], ['Exploring  RawaPening Lake of Salatiga - FOOTBALL MATCH IN MEDELLIN', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-92'], ['FOREST BATHING AND CREATING MEMORIES - Fantasy Photo~Shoot with A Unicorn...', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-93'], ['Fantasy adventure in the mountains - Fazendo Arte na Serra da Cantareira!', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-94'], ['Faça acrobacia em tecido como circense - Film your experience in Osaka', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-95'], ['FilmNeverDies-Filmphotography Workshop - Fishing with the Presidents', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-96'], ['Fishing, Malecon and Sunset - Florist in Paris', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-97'], ['Florist terrace & aperol spritz - Follow a historian through Havana', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-98'], ['Follow a local in vibrant East London - Food, Fotos & The French', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-99'], ['Food, Nature and Art on Tuscan Hills - Fossil Recovery Exploration', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-100'], ['Fossil hunting, Lets GO! - French food market tour & aperitif', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-101'], ['French macarons baking class - Full day surf experience', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-102'], ['Full day trail ride - Gaelic Craic and Cuisine', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-103'], ['Gain insight from a spiritual healer - Gems of Rome...', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-104'], ['Generations of Beekeeping - Get uplifted with gospel in Harlem', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-105'], ['Get ur Shine On Moonshine/Whiskey Tour - Glenorchy and Paradise Explorer', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-106'], ['Gliding on the Ice in the Red Dot - Goat Yoga!', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-107'], ['Goatherd for one day! - Graffiti, Street & Young Art in Vienna', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-108'], ['Grampians hike & waterfalls - Guide tours with E-bike in Menorca', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-109'], ['Guided  Photo Tour ART Walk - Guitar workshop for the Byron Vibe', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-110'], ['Gulf Coast Birding For Beginners - Hand Building with clay in Brooklyn', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-111'], ['Hand Coffee Roasting & Cupping Class - Hang loose w/ Island Style Surf School', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-112'], ['Hang out in Shibuya and craft bonsai - Have a personal photographer for a day', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-113'], ['Have a picnic in a national park - Helicopter tour from Paris to Versailles', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-114'], ['Helicopter tour in São Paulo - Hidden Sculpture Stories Tour', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-115'], ['Hidden Sights & Cosmopolitan Magic - Hike Forest+ City Summit+ Rose Garden', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-116'], ['Hike Gracia hills for view & workout - Hike the Braids and Blackford Hill', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-117'], ['Hike the Bridge to Nowhere - Hiking Ajusco (1day)', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-118'], ['Hiking Ancient Mountain Olive Trees - Hill Country Estate Winery Tour', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-119'], ['Hill Country Yoga Hike - History and Tapas', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-120'], ['History and art inside Tijuca forest - Home-based cooking class in Panaji', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-121'], ['Home-cooked traditional Indian Food - Horseback ride California cowboy style', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-122'], ['Horseback ride and lunch with a farmer - Hungarian Cooking Class & Market Walk', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-123'], ['Hungarian pasta workshop and dinner - Ikebana experience', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-124'], ['Ikebana exprence - In the middle of the wet forest.', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-125'], ['In the trails of Rio - Inside Scoop LA', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-126'], ['Inside Showjumping with a Journalist - Interactive experience of lightpainting room', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-127'], ['Interactive outdoor navigation course - Invigorating Yoga Flow at Balboa Park', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-128'], ['Invitation To Ginza Personal Shopping - JUNGLE ART WALK TULUM', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-129'], ['JUNGLE IN THE CITY - Jazz in Cape Town with Lee Thomson', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-130'], ['Jazz in a Secret Venue - Joshua Tree Macramé Journey', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-131'], ['Joshua Tree Recording Studio & Lodging - Kamikochi hike and visit the Shrine', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-132'], ['Kanazawa Haul at Depachika - Kayak with the Dolphins', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-133'], ['Kayak&Snorkeling experience in Genoa - Kitesurf In Lake Garda', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-134'], ['Kitesurf Lecce-Scuola Kite Salento - Kundalini Yoga to awaken Inner Lover', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-135'], ['Kundalini Yoga, Gong and Yogi Tea - LGBTQ+ History Tour of Brighton', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-136'], ['LGBTQ+ queer and trans tour of London - Lamawandern im Mostviertel', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-137'], ['Lamb Farm Life - Learn 3D printing at Maker Bean Cafe!', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-138'], ['Learn 3D printing: design a souvenir - Learn Pencak Silat (Bali Martial Art)', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-139'], ['Learn Phone Photography in Mongkok - Learn and indulge in Quercy cuisine', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-140'], ['Learn and play poker in Barão Geraldo - Learn how to wakeboard', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-141'], ['Learn how to wakeboard or wakesurf - Learn to DJ and dance at a queer club', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-142'], ['Learn to DJ at Private Studio - Learn to bake sourdough in my kitchen', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-143'], ['Learn to bake traditional Irish Breads - Learn to play badminton!', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-144'], ['Learn to play poker from a Vegas pro - Legends and secrets with traditional music', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-145'], ["Lei Po'o (Flower Crown) Workshop - Let's learn how to wearing kimono", '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-146'], ["Let's learn to SKETCH & DRAW! - Life changing Hike on Crowders Mtn.", '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-147'], ['Life coaching with horses - Lisbon with the historic tram', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-148'], ["Lisbon's CatWalk - Living the Santa Cruz Canyon!", '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-149'], ['Living the dying city! - London Chicken Wing Tour!', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-150'], ['London Christmas Lights Running Tour - Luis Barragán en 5 tiempos.', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-151'], ['Lujan de Cuyo Private Wine Tour - Macaron Class in Paris', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-152'], ["Macaron Masterclass in Borough - Makati's best food drinks and music", '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-153'], ['Make  Fujiyama Katsu-Curry with a chef - Make Wine Candles+Bottle Cutting (DIY)', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-154'], ['Make Your Leather Tortellino Keychain - Make a seashell frame after a boatride', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-155'], ['Make a signature scent with a perfumer - Make sushi in a traditional folk house', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-156'], ['Make sustainable leather espadrilles - Make your own silk scarf in Paris !', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-157'], ['Make your own silver jewel in Florence - Malen und Zeichnen', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-158'], ['Maleny Yoga Rainforest Wellness - Market Tour and a Home Cooked Meal', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-159'], ['Market Tour&Cook  Kenyan cultural food - Matera Photo Journey', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-160'], ['Mathematics Walking Tour of Amsterdam - Meditazione  rilassamento profondo', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-161'], ['Meditazione e benEssere in spiaggia - Men & Womens Wellness Retreat', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-162'], ['Mental Wellness Picnic Chat - Midday Vermouth Madrileño & Tortilla', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-163'], ['Middle Eastern Food Cooking Class - Mini Horse Experience!', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-164'], ['Mini Nature Retreat - Moniz Family Surf: Private Surf Lesson', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-165'], ['Moniz Family Surf: Waikiki Surf Lesson - Morocco in frames:Culture &photography', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-166'], ['Mortadella & Bologna: a love story - Mountain plateau hike (5-7 hr)', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-167'], ['Mountain summit and cozy restaurant - Music, Mummies, and Museums!', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-168'], ['Music, art, history, Rio nightlife - NEW! Amsterdam light cruise', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-169'], ['NEW! Aperitivo tour - Fun Fun Fun! ❤️ - National Arboretum and #madeinDC Tour', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-170'], ['National Gallery with an Art Historian - Nature trails & Birding near Cali', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-171'], ['Nature walk near Hotspring in Jozankei - Night Cheese: California Artisans', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-172'], ["Night Cherry Viewing - Nonna Cecilia's Pasta Workshop!", '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-173'], ['Noodle & Roll & Water Puppet Theater - Obstacle Course Adventure', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-174'], ['Ocean Beach Coffee Cart Bike Tour - Old Montreal: Intimate & Personalized', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-175'], ['Old Quebec : Mesdames & Mesdemoiselles - Ontdek de ambacht van het jam maken', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-176'], ['OoLong Tea Tasting - Osaka Old City Walk Tour with  Sweets!', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-177'], ['Osaka Shinsekai/Dotonbori Walking Tour - PASTA MATRICIANA   MAKING CLASS', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-178'], ['PASTA grani antichi  PANE lievito nat - Paddle with the Penguins', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-179'], ['Paddle your way in history - Paint a skateboard deck with an artist', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-180'], ['Paint a surfboard to send home! - Painting on the Amalfi Coast.', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-181'], ['Painting on the Pier - Paris fabrics & crafts', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-182'], ['Paris for Families - Passeio a cavalo no por do Sol', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-183'], ['Passeio agradável no bairro do Bexiga! - Pedal untamed back roads of Outaouais', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-184'], ['Pedala nelle pinete di Ravenna - Personal Shopping Consultant', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-185'], ['Personal Shopping For Bespoke Suits - Photo Session in beautiful Basel', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-186'], ['Photo Session in sunny Ibiza - Photo tour of Dublin city', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-187'], ["Photo tour on bike with an expert - Photographing in 'off-piste' Tokyo.", '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-188'], ['Photographing in Palermo markets - Photoshoot for yoga lovers in Paris', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-189'], ['Photoshoot from Varadero to Havana - Pick plant n Cook,KANOM JAAK,dessert', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-190'], ['Pick wild apples and can applesauce - Pizza Class on a Renaissance Terrace', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-191'], ['Pizza Cooking Class in Milan - Play the Chinese ink art with Runkuan', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-192'], ['Play the Fiddle in Under an Hour - Por los Cerros de Santiago.', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-193'], ['Por los cementerios de Chepe. - Pose for pin-ups with a photographer', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-194'], ['Pose for portraits in Cambridge - Prague experience: archaeology&history', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-195'], ['Prague for Locals and You - Private Alpine Backpacking Trip', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-196'], ['Private Amalfi & Positano HalfDay tour - Private Yoga Class & Eco Snack', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-197'], ['Private Yoga Class for All Levels - Professional photos of your LA Vacay!', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-198'], ['Professional photoshoot by the sea - Pêche dans le Parc du Mercantour', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-199'], ['Pêche des Calamars en mer - Rafting the Isar', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-200'], ['Rafting trip-Snorkeling&cliff jumping - Recording Studio Magic (Immersive)', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-201'], ['Recording your own k-pop song - Relaxing Costarican Typical Trails', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-202'], ['Relaxing Countryside : Somewhere Snowy - Ride OFF Road in Puerto Rico', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-203'], ['Ride Retired Racehorses at Lake Fork - River hike captured on drone video', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-204'], ['River view cooking with super mom chef - Romancing the Bean', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-205'], ['Romantic "Aperitivo" with lake view - Rugged North Cascades Private Day Tour', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-206'], ['Ruin Pub Crawl with a Local Hostess - Running Tour of Brooklyn!', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-207'], ['Running Tour of San Diego - SAORI freestyle weaving for everyone', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-208'], ['SASHIKO; Learn the Japanese embroidery - SUP around Balboa Isle & the Back Bay', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-209'], ['SUP at sunset - Sail around the city with a boat lover', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-210'], ['Sail at Sunset in Porto - Sails, Whales, and Trails', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-211'], ['Sailtour Lake Lucerne - Samurai Kendo Experience', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-212'], ['Samurai Ninja Experience & Guided Tour - Sardinia: sip by sip', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-213'], ['Sardinian identity in the kitchen - Scotch Whisky & Cheese Tasting', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-214'], ['Scotland Adventure Adrenaline Day - Seaside Yoga', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-215'], ['Seaside bike ride and paddle surfing - Secretos de la Perla Tapatía', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-216'], ['Secretos del centro de Coyoacán - Segeln in Berlin', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-217'], ['Segeltörn auf dem Steinhuder Meer - Seville From The Rooftops', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-218'], ['Seville Great Experience in E-Bike - Shmurgle a Goat, Cosy Winter Edition', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-219'], ['Shochu tasting workshop in Asakusa - Shop-til-you-drop with Fashion Stylist', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-220'], ['Shopper bag making class - Silicon Valley High Tech Company Tour', '/sitemaps/v2/experiences_pdp-L1-221']]}
```